# CMake Compiling Error : blueworkforce / bluezero

Tags: c++, windows, build, cmake

I am attempting to build [CoppeliaRobotics/bluezero](https://github.com/CoppeliaRobotics/bluezero) from the source in windows 10.

This is so I can use the Python API of the http://www.coppeliarobotics.com/ software.

I have installed ZeroMQ via vcpkg and also "downloaded" ZeroMQ from https://zeromq.org/download/

But I am not sure how to get past this error when I build.

When I run the build command

```
 cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DBUILD_GUI=ON -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

I get the following error.

```
..
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE)
CMake Error at E:/cmake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find ZMQ (missing: ZMQ_LIBRARIES ZMQ_INCLUDE_DIRS) (Required is
  at least version "4.1.4")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  E:/cmake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/Modules/FindZMQ.cmake:54 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:59 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/admini/bluezero/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/admini/bluezero/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Then CMakeError.log says

```
Determining if the include file pthread.h exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Users/admini/bluezero/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_19eab.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Framework

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.24.28315 for x64

  CheckIncludeFile.c

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_19eab.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_19eab.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue C:\Users\admini\bluezero\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c

C:\Users\admini\bluezero\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c(1,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pthread.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\admini\bluezero\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_19eab.vcxproj]
```

CmakeOutPut.log says

```
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/Users/admini/bluezero/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_fbd1d.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Framework

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.24.28315 for x64

  CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR /Fo"cmTC_fbd1d.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_fbd1d.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue "E:\cmake\share\cmake-3.16\Modules\CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp"

  cmTC_fbd1d.vcxproj -> C:\Users\admini\bluezero\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_fbd1d.exe
```

I am not sure how to proceed or troubleshoot further.

Comment: The error message "Could NOT find ZMQ" means that CMake cannot find ZeroMQ library. There is noting in `CMakeError.log` and `CMakeOutput.log` about that problem.

Comment: I figured the same thing, I am just not sure how to make CMake find it.